# Writing to /dev/kmsg with udev run

Tags: udev

I have written a simple udev rule to name my usb device:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0658", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0200", SYMLINK+="ttyUSB-ZStick-5G"
```

udev offers ways to run custom scripts on certain events ([ref](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html):

```
KERNEL=="sdb", RUN+="/usr/bin/my_program"
```

However, what i would like for the above solution is to just print some info that will show up in `dmesg`. This isn't a complexity that would require a separate script.

Below is something what I was ideally hoping to work:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0658", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0200", SYMLINK+="ttyUSB-ZStick-5G", RUN+="echo 'Made symlink: ttyUSB-ZStick-5G' > /dev/kmsg"
```

Ideas on how to do this?

Comment: `udev` is not a shell. Use `sh -c 'echo ...`

Answer (score 1):

As the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udev.7.html#RULES_FILES) explains:

> The program name and following arguments are separated by spaces. Single quotes can be used to specify arguments with spaces.

The string passed to `RUN` is not fed to a shell. It's just split at whitespace with a crude quoting mechanism. If you want to perform a redirection, you need to invoke a shell.

```
… RUN+="sh -c 'echo Made symlink: ttyUSB-ZStick-5G > /dev/kmsg'"
```

Calling a script would be clearer.